# Setting object property by string name

Tags: typescript, reflection

Very new to typescript and am trying to port some C# code.  I need to be able to set an instances properties by property string name.

In C# I do this with reflection, but how can I do this in typescript?

The following is a simplified example:

```
class BaseClazz {
  baseA?: string;
  baseB?: string;
}

class DerivedClazz extends BaseClazz {
  derived1?: number;
  derived2?: number;
  array1?: number[];
  array2?: number[];
}
```

I want a function that can set the various properties by their string name:

```
function assign(clazz: BaseClass, propertyName: string, value: any) {
  ...
}
```

In theory I can call it as follows and each of the 4 properties would be set:

```
test:BaseClazz = new DerivedClazz();
assign(test, "baseA", "a");
assign(test, "baseB", "b");
assign(test, "derived1", 1);
assign(test, "derived2", 2);
assign(test, "array1", [1, 2, 3, 4]);
assign(test, "array2", [5, 6, 7, 8]);
```

Comment: You can do this with generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq3Jkw), although you don't want to annotate `test` as `BaseClazz` because then the compiler won't think it's safe to call, say, `assign(test, "derived1", 1)`;  But in JavaScript/TypeScript all objects are property bags so you don't need to use "reflection" to do this, you just assign a value to the property.  Does this fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yep, that's nice and clean and it works.  I'm just reading what you did, and am I correct that its type safe?  value:T[K] reads to me like the value has to be of the object T's property K.  Very cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all object types in JavaScript are essentially property bags, you can write `assign()` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function that accepts any object for its first argument (not just a subtype of `BaseClazz`):

```
function assign<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
    obj: T, key: K, val: T[K]
) {
    obj[key] = val; // okay
}
```

Here `obj` is of generic type `T` [constrained to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `object`, and `key` is of generic type `K` [constrained to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) the keys of `T` (using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html)), and `val` is of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`, which is the type of the property at `obj[key]`.

If you really want to limit the function to be for subtypes of `BaseClazz` you can write `T extends BaseClazz` instead of `T extends object`, but unless you need other functionality of `BaseClazz` inside `assign()` there's not much reason to.

---

Let's make sure this works:

```
const test = new DerivedClazz();
assign(test, "baseA", "a"); // okay
assign(test, "baseB", 123); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

assign(test, "baseB", "b"); // okay
assign(test, "baseC", "x"); // error!
// Argument of type '"baseC"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof DerivedClazz'

assign(test, "derived1", 1); // okay
assign(test, "derived2", 2); // okay
assign(test, "array1", [1, 2, 3, 4]); // okay
assign(test, "array2", [5, 6, 7, 8]); // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler complains if you pass in a `key` that is not known to exist on `test`, and it complains if you pass in a `value` that is not of the type of the property corresponding to indexing into `test` with the key at `key`.

---

This is about as type-safe as TypeScript typically gets for generics.  It's not perfectly [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).  For example, if the `key` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) then the `value` is also allowed to be of the corresponding union type, which could be weird:

```
assign(test, Math.random() < 0.999 ? "derived1" : "array1", [1]); // okay, 
// but 99.9% chance of being bad
```

But unsoundness runs through the language, intentionally, for better or worse (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825#issuecomment-306272034) on [microsoft/TypeScript#9825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825)).  There are other ways to put the wrong thing into a property, since TypeScript treats object types as covariant in their properties, which again, could be weird:

```
interface Foo {
    baseA?: string | number;
}
const foo: Foo = test; // okay because DerivedClazz extends Foo
assign(foo, "baseA", 123); // okay, but oops
foo.baseA = 456; // same thing directly
console.log(test.baseA.toUpperCase()); //  RUNTIME ERROR!
```

So take care when combining subtyping with property assignment!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4BeroG8BQ0-QCNEBBAfgC5oIAXAJwEsA7AcwG5d8iIFYKq6mbbAF9s2UJBgARBAwBuCACYow6aAgAe1BI0Ux43FWpz5oi2fQWKAjH0YBXALYFZ7U+flKATHacvabvhgtLRgAJ62lA7OsgDaALqBeMGhYT5RfnGJImLYAGb2jMDU9AD2jNCS9MyMADwAKupaOnrQpQQAVgjFADTQANJN2rowANYIYaV50PUAfAAUHHjtHZT1feNhlP19cmAga7H98dgAlFhLbZ2xm-HQALzQeyDsouLlNNDan4+MCADu0BknmUaFQ81O7CqNXm32ofQARFwEMQEYiwAjIdAAPTYtqjcLYaGMWEIGiI5GwNHQaxeADMWNx6hCpVoAEJsEyALQ83l8-k82bQAB+os5eOItGYTh01Da02oYQADghoAByaL+NXQegwRilOXEsAEECq6ilaBK4JgRwIbS0eVfZWqtU0BgsNViYmk8nQJGIKkUzGsHF40oEsJEqDVElwimIJDUhEaYOh5m0VkcpmS6W2xhyqZOlXq-2GBHa3XQfWG6M1Y2mr4Wq2hW32x2K4tqzaF4GWJRGVCeqMQGM++F+jx9mzU6yMsMR4ejuMTixWLzUrxz-GE73LhEpcLWamxax9Lx9Ol9AAs8S34Z3tdjZPH+5C4XXfViAFY+gA2PoAOx9AAHLeIZMvekaLjCy4ALJgNQAAWAB0oS6KUjgQtAtTQAADMhACcRHQKQK4gke0CUK+qRHp+1hgWmkF9OKhD2HKRGEQApNAwCIWARSqoWLiCIQYCKGITD2nkYDAKqABipQWiYnAkHwboiQAPlWmQBDkwAfHKeSKZQCkWo8cLgfO4SEN0YD2NwQKrv2YJDC0MCmdBJJGaU8bcKifS0gylnbmEfQEGxbSlEqED5IpyHIsQDzQFeX6-sFEA2maiEiUwIBMAg7yMBApSmshIClMwY7xSQyHmgAqkqKq0EgiAQlugC8G4ApTvQAASnVABy9QAJKwQAotAo09T1ADyPVskAA)